# Node.js Webm live stream server: issues with <video> tag

Tags: html, node.js, ffmpeg, html5-video, webm

I'm using Node.js as stream server to stream realtime Webm videos that is sent by FFMPEG (executed from another application, the stream is done via HTTP) and received by a webapp that uses the  tag.

This is what I'm doing: FFMPEG streams the received frames using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f rawvideo  -pix_fmt bgra -s 640x480 
-i \\.\pipe\STREAM_PIPE -r 60 
-f segment  -s 240x160 -codec:v libvpx  -f webm 
http://my.domain.com/video_stream.webm
```

(the stream comes from an application that uses the Kinect as source and communicates with FFMPEG through a pipe, sending one frame after another)

When the webapp connects, it receives immediately this response from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
content-type: video/webm
cache-control: private
connection: close
Date: Fri, 06 Dec 2013 14:36:31 GMT
```

and a Webm header (previously stored on the server, with the same resolution and frame rate of the source stream and tested as working on VLC) is immediately appended. Then the webapp starts to receive the data streamed by FFMPEG. Here is a screenshot of Mkvinfo GUI showing the fields of the header:

[image: Header screenshot]

However, even if the Network tab of the Chrome console shows that there is an actual stream of data (meaning that what is streamed is not completely garbage, otherwise the connection would be dropped), the player doesn't display anything. We tried to manually prepend our header to the dumped video received by the webapp and VLC plays it just fine, but this is not happening with the  tag.

What can cause this problem? Are we missing something about the encoding on the FFMPEG side or we stored wrong values on the header (or they're not enough)?

PS: I cannot rely on an extern stream server.

PPS: We tried the following experiments:

- substituting the video header with the one stored in the server makes the video playable on both vlc and video tag
- if we dump the video that is already started (without an header) and we prepend the video header stored in the server or even its original header, the video is playable in VLC but not on the  tag (we're carefully prepending the header just before the beggining of the cluster).

Comment: do you have a github repo I could fork to play around with this a bit?  I'm about to tackle a project for work that would likely encounter this issue... so might as well see if I can help you in the process.

Answer (score 1):

There so many variables added to this problem when considering you're using a technology outside of(and not integrated into) node to stream your video. This could cause issues with the loadbalancer or proxy you are using, or it could be that you're hosting 2 applications on the same port.

Could you do the streaming in just node? Or could you even just stream ffmpeg to the filesystem and stream that with node.fs.readStream()? This would reuse the same webserver instead of spawning an entirely new server on the same box. And if youre just streaming that content from point to point, then you need to buffer the data coming through and forward the buffer as a stream through node.

The reason why technologies get integrated, wrapped, and extended into other frameworks is for reasons of uniformity. Reading your question, though its well detailed, it still leaves a lot aloof. This could lead into question about how ffmpeg converts and serves http content, and how your loadbalancer/proxy handles that. Does node have anything to do with this? Is there a replacement for ffmpeg so you can standardize around node's framework? Is node right for this applications?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found that the actual problem is the HTML5 <video>. In Nodejs you have 2 ways to send data with http response: write() and end()(the first sends data, the latter can send data and conclude the response).
The video player starts to play only when the res has ended. In live streams I can't end a res containing my video data, as I don't know when the stream will end. We know that Flumotion stream server can do this with a single HTTP 200 res (same as ours except for HTTP 1.0 vs 1.1), but we can't figure out how.Do you have any advice/info about video tag implementation?

Comment: You could use websockets to stream mpeg video, and decode client side with the [jsmpeg library](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg). But that won't be webm format. If you have node keep streaming a file won't if eventually end the stream once the stream is over and the buffer file ended?

Comment: unfortunately I have some strict requirements on my project: the stream has to be done via http, with a webm (or ogg) encoding, and the chunks of data coming from ffmpeg have to be sent in real time, so no file is involved or allowed. as i was saying previously, flumotion do something like that, i just don't get how it convinces the video player to playback the stream as soon as it receives anything!

Comment: Then you're completely right. HTML5 does not support this whatsoever. In fact no browser does currently. This is a reason youtube still uses flash. I believe the problem with implementing realtime video in HTML5 is the conflict of HTTP standards which don't comply. You're real problem probably lies within the standards of HTTP. I think the HTTP response fields `Content-Length` and `Content-Range` need to be declared to send any kind of data, otherwise the HTTP packet is fragmented to an unknown amount. Which is bad practice on any protocol.

Comment: All-in-all HTTP doesn't support this kind of streaming. This is basically why webSockets were created. Getting it to work would probably require some very "hackish" methods.

Comment: Actually seems HTTP1.1 brings a solution to the table, but who knows if html5 <video> supports it. Have you looked into [Chunked Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)?

Comment: yep, but not working (at least, not what i want to achieve). before going with the 200 response i played a lot with 206 range responses(with all the parameters like chunked encoding), no results. that's when i found flumotion and it's way to handle the stream with a simple (?) 200 response. I also looked a bit in them source code but i couldn't find something useful (or maybe i haven't dug deep). anyone with information about it's welcome :)

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?